# How do I hide GCDAsyncSocket warnings for 10.9 deprecations

Tags: objective-c, gcdasyncsocket

10.9 deprecated a bunch of SSL stuff, how do I hide the warnings or fix the issues?

Comment: Rewrite the thing.  It would be a great exercise on top of figuring out more platform-specific crypto built into iOS or OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn deprecation warnings on and off in your target's build settings. To do so, click on your project in the Project Navigator, select the target you're working on and show the Build Settings for that target. You can use the search box to search for "deprecate", and you should find an LLVM warning for "Deprecated Functions" and set it to "No".

Be aware that if you do this, you can compile without (deprecation) warnings, but you're setting yourself up to have broken code in the future. At some point you really should rewrite that code using the new proper method as @CodaFi mentions above.